# Using Pre-Compiler Directives in C# to toggle Debug Functionality

Tags: c#, precompile

I am attempting to use Pre-compiler directives to toggle certain features in my application. I am using Pre-compiler directives as opposed to `const static` variables because these features will not occur in the release version of the application.

Is it true that C# does not allow for all C Pre-compiler commands, ie, `#if X > Y` & etc.? My below code is throwing compiler errors. Is it possible to use Pre-compiler directives to toggle functionality in my application?

My solution is a very 'C++/C' way of achieving this functionality. What is the C# way of achieving this functionality?

```
#define DEBUG                   1 // Not allowed to assign values to constants?
#define USE_ALTERNATE_METHOD    0

public class MyApplication
{
    public MyApplication()
    {
        #if DBEUG > 0 // Not allowed these kinds of directives?
            RegressionTests.Run();
        #endif // DEBUG > 0
    }

    public void myMethod
    {
        #if USE_ALTERNATE_METHOD > 0
            // Do alternate stuff
        #else 
            // Do regular stuff
        #endif // USE_ALTERNATE_METHOD > 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying just `#if DEBUG` does the work.

You cannot use pre-processor definitives like `#define DEBUG                   1` .

However you can just specify `#define DEBUG` or `#define CustomDefinition` and use it with the `Conditional` attribute.

Eg,

You can just do this:

```
#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine("This will work in DEBUG mode alone");
#endif
```

Or you can specify `conditional-attributes` on top of the method that you wanna execute only in the debug mode.

Eg,

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void ExecuteOnlyInDebugMode()
{
     // do stuff you wanna do.
}
```

For your example it has to be like this:

```
#define DEBUG                  
#define USE_ALTERNATE_METHOD       
public class MyApplication
{
    public MyApplication()
    {
        #if DEBUG
            RegressionTests.Run();
        #endif 
    }

    public void myMethod
    {
        #if USE_ALTERNATE_METHOD 
            // Do alternate stuff
            //do not execute the following. just return.
        #endif
            // Do regular stuff

    }
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856824/what-is-the-usage-of-if-debug-pre-processor-directive-in-c-when-must-we-use-t) . Beautifully explained.

Also, read more that `Conditional` attribute, [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx)

Comment: But doesn't that mean that if I want to turn off `USE_ALTERNATE_METHOD` that I have to completely remove this line/definition instead of just changing its value from `1` to `0`

Comment: Yup, `you have to do that`.